# Is there some way to guarantee relative order of destructors?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor

if I have something along the lines of:

```
auto foo=Foo(Bar())
```

where Foo's constructor takes a const reference to Bar, is there some way to ensure that Bar's destructor will not get called before the destructor on foo at the end of the scope of foo, so that the reference to Bar will still be valid even in foo's destructor?

Comment: If you want `Bar` to be destructed after `foo`, you need to make its scope larger than the scope of `foo`. You can do `const auto bar = Bar(); auto foo = Foo(bar);`.

Comment: Is there reason this is tagged as c++17 rather than just c++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relative order of the destructors is guaranteed.

```
auto foo=Foo(Bar());
```

Since `Bar()` is a temporary, then it is guaranteed to be destructed at the end of the expression: aka the semicolon.  You are absolutely guaranteed that the `Bar` is destroyed before `foo`.

There is no way to extend the lifetime of this temporary, you'll have to make a copy of it (potentially by moving it). Alternatively:

```
{
   Bar b;
   auto foo=Foo(b);
}
```

Since the objects in a single scope are destroyed in the opposite order they're constructed, then since these are in the same scope, `b` will be destroyed after `foo` is destroyed.

Comment: >There is no way to extend the lifetime of this temporary, you'll have to make a copy of it.



Probably better to move rather than copy in this case.

Comment: @Stu technically, the move constructor is one way to make a copy of an object's current state, but I've clarified the sentence.